# ssh-keygen utility

Tags: ssh, ssh-keygen

Is this possible to change the path that ssh-keygen use the files from?
The default one is `$HOME/.ssh/` so is this possible to change this?
Like for example when using ssh-keygen -R to remove the host from known_hosts file how can I 
provide another known_hosts file (`$HOME/.ssh_other/known_hosts` for example) other than the default one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the manpage of ssh-keygen:

```
ssh-keygen -R hostname [-f known_hosts_file]
```

...

```
-f filename
         Specifies the filename of the key file.
```