# The local computer connecting to ssh host is returning an error?

Tags: ssh, remote, openssh

I'm trying to figure out how to overcome this error: 
I read some similar posts but nothing I could find was straightforward, I was hoping to get some advice on what I can do

```
macminngh:MDATA sondosayyash$ ssh -Y -v s1@goblin.sharcnet.ca
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to goblin.sharcnet.ca [199.241.162.29] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/sondosayyash/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/sondosayyash/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/sondosayyash/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/sondosayyash/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/sondosayyash/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/sondosayyash/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/sondosayyash/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/sondosayyash/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't an error on the remote host, that is an issue on the client side.

```bsh
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/sondosayyash/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
```

The first line is key; it cannot find the file, `/Users/sondosayyash/.ssh/id_rsa`.

There is no such directory called `/Users/` by default at least, on a Unix-like machine. Typically, this would be `/home/sondosayyash/.ssh/id_rsa`.

You can verify this, by navigating to your `.ssh` directory in your home directory.

```
# Navigate to /home/user/.ssh
cd ~/.ssh

# Validate the absolute path of your .ssh directory
pwd

# Display the contents of the directory
ls
```

If there is no `id_rsa` key file in this directory, then you will need to create a key pair. There is already an answer for creating a key pair on this site:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99330/247886

Comment: `debug1: identity file /Users/sondosayyash/.ssh/id_rsa type -1` this is only an error if there's supposed to be a key file. It's perfectly possible to use ssh without a key.

Comment: So should I do the following: `ssh-keygen -R /Users/sondosayyash/.ssh  [-f id_rsa]`?

Comment: No, there is no `/Users`.

Comment: @LucasRamage I tried `ssh-keygen -R /home/sondosayyash/.ssh [-f id_rsa]` and it still didn't resolve the issue

Comment: @Kenster so it's clear that there is supposed to be a keyfile since its an error.

Comment: @LucasRamage I just checked my system and it appears that .ssh is located in /Users/sondosayyash/.ssh

Comment: What system is this?